# Using pandas to compute shares of columns that have particular values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with two columns: keys and values. I want to construct a new column as follows. For each key, compute the frequency of each value, out of the total values for this key.

I have code that achieves it, but I suspect that there must be a much simpler way to do this in pandas. Here is an example:

```
def fun(sd):
    uniqueValuesList = list(sd.drop_duplicates().dropna())
    if len(uniqueValuesList)==0:
        return pd.Series([0]*sd.shape[0], index=sd.index)
    elif len(uniqueValuesList)==1:
        return pd.Series([1]*sd.shape[0], index=sd.index)
    else:
        valuesList = list(sd)
        valuesArr = np.array(valuesList)        
        stackedValuesDf = pd.DataFrame([valuesArr]*len(valuesArr))
        boolDf = stackedValuesDf==valuesList
        frac = boolDf.sum() / boolDf.shape[0]
        return frac

keys =   ['1', '1', '1', '2', '3']
values = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', np.nan]
df = pd.DataFrame([keys, values]).T
df.columns = ['keys', 'values']
print(df.groupby('keys').values.apply(fun))
```

This gives the desired output:

```
0    0.333333
1    0.666667
2    0.666667
3    1.000000
4    0.000000
```

That is, for the key `'1'`, `'a'` appears once  and `'b'` appears twice, so they get 0.33 and 0.67, respectively. For `'2'` there is a singleton key so it get 1. For `'3'` there are no keys, so it gets 0.

What is simpler pandas way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `transform` `pd.Series.value_counts`, so instead you can use two transforms with `size`:

```
m = df['values'].notnull()

df.loc[m, 'per'] = (df.loc[m].groupby(['keys', 'values'])['values'].transform('size')
                     / df.groupby('keys')['values'].transform('size'))

df['per'] = df['per'].fillna(0)

#  keys values       per
#0    1      a  0.333333
#1    1      b  0.666667
#2    1      b  0.666667
#3    2      c  1.000000
#4    3    NaN  0.000000
```

---

Alteratively, with a merge:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('keys')['values']
         .apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True)
         .to_frame('per'))
df1.index.names=['keys', 'values']

df = df.merge(df1.reset_index(), how='left')
df['per'] = df['per'].fillna(0)
```